# Express csurf middleware always accepted even if i don't attach _csrf in the req.body from react app but api works in postman as expected

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, csrf, csrf-token

Hi i am trying to acieve **CSRF protection in react js and express js** application. The express api is working properly with postman, when i attach **_csrf : token** with the **req.body** then it works otherwise it throw invalid csrf token. thats perfect.But when i call the api from the react app using axios its working without the csrf token ,please help. thanks

#### Here is the code for express:

```
const express = require('express')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
const csurf = require('csurf')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({ origin: true, credentials: true }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(csurf({
    cookie: {
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 30//30 seconds
    }
}));
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN', req.csrfToken());
    next();
});

//do some operation (this should be csrf protected )
//its protected in postman but not in my react app
app.post('/post', authMid, (req, res) => {
    console.log("req.headers - ", req.headers['x-xsrf-token']);
    res.json({ name: "some operation happen" })
});
```

#### My React Code:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { useState } from 'react'

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:2727/' //api base url
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true

//react App componet
function App() {

  const [msg, setMsg] = useState("")


  const doOperation= async () => {
    try {
      //i don't attach the XSRF-TOKEN but still the request is successfull 
      //but its not successfull if the XSRF-TOKEN is not attach in post man.
      const res = await axios.post('/post')
      console.log(res.data);
      setMsg(res.data)
    } catch (e) {
      setM(e.message)
    }
  }

  

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={doOperation}>do Operation</button>

      <h1>{msg}</h1>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**X-XSRF-TOKEN** is **automatically set and sent in the request headers by Axios** in my react app that's why when I did not set the _csrf token it still works. But in postman, it doesn't work that way that's why I need to add the _csrf token manually in the body.